# How to align 3 images responsive in HTML email?

Tags: css, html-email

I have an HTML email. I want 3 images side by side on a large screen with more then 900px width, like this:
[image]

On a mobile phone I would like to have the boxed below each other like this:

[image]

I want to achieve this in Gmail app and webbrowser. Unfortunately, I cant use media queries because they are not supported in Gmail app (and in my experience they also didn't work for Gmail web browser): https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/

How can I do this? My basic Idea was to use a table like this:

```
<table width="100%" align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table class="my-table-size" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <img style="display: inline-block" src="http://www.my.dev/box.jpg" alt="logo" height="90" >
                        <img style="display: inline-block" src="http://www.my.dev/box.jpg" alt="logo" height="90" class="middleimage">
                        <img style="display: inline-block" src="http://www.my.dev/box.jpg" alt="logo" height="90" >
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it seems that the "inline-block" style is ignored, because the images are always below each other as in - even if there would be enough space to put them side by side.

[image]

I can give the table a fix width like

```
<table class="my-table-size" width="900px" >
```

but then it will always have width 900px also on mobile. So it will look on any device like this:

[image]

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Not talking about gmail, just general email layouts. We need to  use for all clients (sadly for outlook, the worst and more needed) nested tables as you have done. and forget about biger screens. 900px is too large in my experience (I use 600px). Make the layout as you have already done (column). You shoudn't expect people opening emails in a full width browser, specially these days when most emails are open by mobiles phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is commonly solved by use of the "fluid hybrid" technique. I'm going to steal from https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919 for this, but it's a very common technique (there are others around too).

The essential code is below:

```
<div class="three-col" style="font-size:0;text-align:center;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <table role="presentation" width="100%" style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:220px;padding:10px;" valign="top">
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:220px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="padding:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">
            [content goes here]
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;padding:10px;" valign="top">
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:220px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="padding:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">
            [content goes here]
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;padding:10px;" valign="top">
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:220px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <div style="padding:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">
            [content goes here]
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

Now, you can still use media queries to enhance the experience for those email clients that do support embedded `<style>s`.

So you can add this, as one possible example, in the `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
        .three-col .column {
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 460px) {
        .three-col .column {
            max-width: 50% !important;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 461px) {
        .three-col .column {
            max-width: 33.3% !important;
        }
        .two-col .column {
            max-width: 50% !important;
        }
        .sidebar .small {
            max-width: 16% !important;
        }
        .sidebar .large {
            max-width: 84% !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```